# Getting "none" in my print statement. Tried different things, none work, to fix

Tags: python

I am assuming that it has something to do with my lack of a return function, but everything I've tried comes back with errors, which makes me think there is something more going on. Also, I'm sure there's a much easier way to do this test and any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your patience and help as I'm completely new to this and learning. The print statement reads as follows:

aaaaNone

aaaaiaAeiaoaiaaiieeiaeuiaaeouaueaoaAiououeaeaEeooeoiNone

So, why the "None"s?

Given by professor:

```
def string_of_vowels(str):
    """
    04: Return a string of all the vowels in a string.
    Input str is a String.
    Your function should return a string of vowels in this string, in the sequence they appear, including the duplicates.
    For example, if the input parameter is "Casablanca", the return value should be "aaaa".
    Be careful: you should count the vowels a, e, i, o, u and their upper letters
    """
```

My coding:

```
    x = str
    i = 0
    while i < len(x):
        if x[i] in ["a"]:
            print ("a", end="")
        elif x[i] in ["A"]:
            print ("A", end="")
        elif x[i] in ["e"]:
            print ("e",end="")
        elif x[i] in ["E"]:
            print ("E", end="")
        elif x[i] in ["i"]:
            print ("i", end="")
        elif x[i] in ["I"]:
            print ("I", end="")
        elif x[i] in ["o"]:
            print ("o", end="")
        elif x[i] in ["O"]:
            print ("O",end="")
        elif x[i] in ["u"]:
            print ("u",end="")
        elif x[i] in ["U"]:
            print ("U",end="")
        i += 1
```

Given by professor:

```
# test for Q4
print(string_of_vowels('Casablanca'))
print(string_of_vowels('''Casablanca is a 1942 American romantic drama film directed by Michael Curtiz and based on Murray Burnett and Joan Alison's unproduced stage play Everybody Comes to Rick's. '''))
```

Comment: "I am assuming that it has something to do with my lack of a return function" I think that's correct. What are the errors you get? It would be much better to ask "Why doesn't this code work?" when its giving you an error than "How do I fix this code?"

Comment: You're print all the vowels in the string inside the function. Then you're returning None. Then you're printing that returned None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a bit long, but take some time to read it. It seems that you already almost have a solution to the problem, so I will give a simpler one here for you to see the beauty of Python, and to show you maybe how to think slightly differently on a problem like this.

### The `in` operator

You seem to already know what `in` does. `x in y` will return true if `x` is in the sequence `y`. I'm using "sequence" here because `y` can actually be any list, tuple, string, (or iterable). So, if you want to check if a character is in a string, you can simply use `in`. For example, `'c' in 'acorn'` returns true, because `'acorn'` has a `'c'` in it. Case matters here.

Now that we know that the `in` operator can work with strings, we can simplify your function a bit. If you want to check if `x` is a vowel, you can do: `x in 'aAeEiIoOuU`, right? Much simpler.

### Using a `for` loop

You use a while loop in your answer, with an index that you look up each time, but a simpler solution would be to iterate each of the characters in the string, like so

```
for c in str:
    if c in 'aAeEiIoOuU':
        # c is a vowel here
```

Now, we can start keeping track of the vowels, by adding only the vowels together, like so:

```
vowels = ""
for c in str:
    if c in 'aAeEiIoOuU':
        vowels += c
```

Here, `vowels += c` means `vowels = vowels + c`, which concatenates the strings. For example, `"aeio" + "u"` results in `"aeiou"`.

At this point, `vowels` contains all of the vowels in `str`, and now all we need to do is return `vowels` from the function. Returning is different then printing, in the sense that printing is like *showing* someone an image of a cake, while returning is giving someone an actual cake.

So, our function ends up looking like this

```
def string_of_vowels(str):
    vowels = ""
    for c in str:
        if c in 'aAeEiIoOuU':
            vowels += c
    return vowels
```

Comment: I knew there was a much simpler way to do this. Thank you so much for the excellent break-down! Is there any particular reason you use "c"? Is it like using i & j for integers, but for string chars? I'll definitely be paying this forward once I know what I'm doing. :)

Comment: I usually use `c` for characters, and `i` and `j` for integers when using ranges, and if I'm iterating a list of special objects, i'll use a more specific name for those.

There's an even shorter way to do this believe it or not, which I can edit the answer to share and explain if you'd like. I'd recommend the approach I posted, however, for a initial Python course.

Comment: Gotcha. I was just curious if that was a standard practice in the coding world. This is certainly helpful. I guess it's pretty obvious I'm learning about loops, iterations, and ranges at this point. I really appreciate the offer, but at the moment, I think I'll stick with your previous coding. I don't want to get too ahead of myself. It makes complete sense and definitely correlates with what I'm being taught currently. Thank you so much again!

Comment: No problem! Super good choice. No reason to blast ahead. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the result of the function even though you're already printing the vowels inside it already.

```
print(string_of_vowels('Casablanca'))
print(string_of_vowels('''Casablanca is a 1942 American romantic drama film directed by Michael Curtiz and based on Murray Burnett and Joan Alison's unproduced stage play Everybody Comes to Rick's. '''))
```

Should be:

```
string_of_vowels('Casablanca')
string_of_vowels('''Casablanca is a 1942 American romantic drama film directed by Michael Curtiz and based on Murray Burnett and Joan Alison's unproduced stage play Everybody Comes to Rick's. ''')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the print statements have to remain, as they are part of the test my professor put into the code. I should have been more explicit about what I started with and where I had to go. Sorry for the lack of info. :/

Comment: @MCraft You can just add everything to a variable then return it

Comment: So instead of printing the result in the function, make a variable and where you have `print()`, put `variableName = variableName + 'Letter'` and at the end of the function, have `return variableName`

Comment: Awesome, I see where you're going with this. Thank you very much! Going to try and fix it. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the function（string_of_vowels）, you have called the print function, and the results have been output to the STDOUT. So you do not need to use the print when call it. Because the Print function returns None (equivalent to print (None)), there will be None in the result.

You just write like this:

```
string_of_vowels('Casablanca')
string_of_vowels('''Casablanca is a 1942 American romantic drama film directed by Michael Curtiz and based on Murray Burnett and Joan Alison's unproduced stage play Everybody Comes to Rick's. ''')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong.Because you did not give the return value, will return to none.You can modify the way you call，like this：

```
string_of_vowels('Casablanca'）
string_of_vowels('''Casablanca is a 1942 American romantic drama film directed by Michael Curtiz and based on Murray Burnett and Joan Alison's unproduced stage play Everybody Comes to Rick's. ''')
```

then will not found 'none',or return a string for function to replace 'print'.